# Remove substring parts that matches where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I used the following method to remove the prefixes in the names, but if there was no space after "MR." such as MR.JOHN SMITH" it would not work properly. any advice on these? How can I remove the substring if it matches the where condition.

```
SELECT LTRIM(REPLACE(firstname, SUBSTRING(firstname, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', 
firstname)), ''))
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE  firstname LIKE 'Mr.%' OR 
firstname LIKE 'Mrs.%' OR  
firstname LIKE 'Miss %' OR  
firstname LIKE 'Dr.%';
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry, I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
SELECT 
LTRIM(REPLACE(firstname, SUBSTRING(firstname, 1,
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.', firstname) > 0 
         THEN CHARINDEX('.', firstname) 
         ELSE CHARINDEX(' ',firstname) END ) , ''))
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE  firstname LIKE 'Mr.%' OR 
firstname LIKE 'Mrs.%' OR  
firstname LIKE 'Miss %' OR  
firstname LIKE 'Dr.%';
```

and an alternative for clear,

```
LTRIM(STUFF(firstname, 1, (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.', firstname) > 0 
                          THEN CHARINDEX('.', firstname) 
                          ELSE CHARINDEX(' ',firstname) END ), ''))
```